# How to read txt file created?

Tags: android, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to retrieve a txt file generated by an apk.

I've already extracted the app from android using adb, unziped/used apktool to get source file, analysed it and discovered the following:

```
this.context.openFileOutput("filename.txt", 0);
localFileOutputStream.write(paramString);
localFileOutputStream.close();
```

As far as I understand it's saving this file *filename.txt* on the local directory of the apk, but searching for it after the unzip there's nothing there.

The main questions here are:

Am I looking on the right place for it?
If so, how can I get this file?

Comment: If the app is creating the text file it's most likely that they didn't include it in the APK file itself as that would be useless. And since it's not creating it to the external storage directory, it's creating it in the apps internal storage directory (Located at a system level folder that requires root access to read, write, or view at root:data\data\com.app.name) So you aren't looking for it in the right place. And if you wish to view that file, it either has to be an app you're currently developing, or you'll have to root your device to access that file. Sorry about that :/

Comment: Ok @AlexHerrera . I'm already using a rooted device. Thanks very much